# Did I should use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() to encode the form data before save to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net

I have done below:

1. Filtered the dangerous char
2. Encoded the form data before save to SQL Server 2008

   ```
   public static string EncodeData(string str)
   {
           string getStr = str;
           getStr = getStr.Replace(";", " ");
           getStr = getStr.Replace("&", "");
           getStr = getStr.Replace("<", "");
           getStr = getStr.Replace(">", "");
           getStr = getStr.Replace("'", "");
           getStr = getStr.Replace("--", "");
           getStr = getStr.Replace("/", " ");
           getStr = getStr.Replace("%", "");
           getStr = getStr.Replace("*", "");
           getStr = getStr.Replace(":", "");
           getStr = getStr.Replace("!", "");
           return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(getStr);
   }
   ```

Is what I have done correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't encode before you store, instead encode at the closest point to output. By encoding before storing you have a couple of problems

1. You're limiting your data to a single format. What if you wanted to return that data as JSON for example? Or RSS? The encoding rules are different, and you've now pretty much forced that data to be HTML.
2. What if the encoder changes due to a bug fix? None of your stored data will get that bug fix applied because you're not encoding after pulling it out of storage.

And as an aside, I agree that you should be using parameterized queries or an ORM that does it for you so you're protected against SQL injection without trying to manually strip characters.

Answer (score 2):

That is completely, 100%, wrong.

You should use *parameters* so that the database engine will send text separately from the SQL queries.

You should not randomly strip characters or apply irrelevant escapes.

Answer (score 0):

Saving characters to database is not that big a problem. Bigger problem is displaying data on a web page. If you are not sure about how safe is your string, then feel free to use HtmlEncode/HtmlDecode while sending data to the browser.